# `shell` process got killed when C-c C-c

Tags: tramp, shell

When `tramp-own-remote-path` is add to `tramp-remote-path`, a shell buffer started with `/ssh:/some_server:/bin/bash` got killed when doing <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> on a running process or empty prompt.

The issue does not happen with `/bin/sh`.

The issue does not happen when `tramp-own-remote-path` is not added to `tramp-remote-path`.

<kbd>C-h k</kbd> tells that <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> is bound to `comint-interrupt-subjob`.

The `bash` version on the remote Ubuntu server (18.04) is `GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`.

My local emacs version is: `GNU Emacs 28.1 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin21.5.0, Carbon Version 165 AppKit 2113.5) of 2022-07-04`.

To reproduce:

1. Run `emacs -Q --eval "(progn (require 'tramp) (add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path 'tramp-own-remote-path))"`.
2. Eval `(find-file "/ssh:some_server:~")`.
3. Run <kbd>M-x</kbd> `shell` and choose `/bin/bash`.
4. Press <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> and notice that the shell *process* is killed.

Is this a tramp bug or bash issue?

---

Update:

I find that removing `eval "$(direnv hook bash)"` in my `.bashrc` solves the issue. But I don't know how it is related `tramp` and `shell`.

Comment: I can't reproduce. `C-c C-c` doesn't kill the process. No idea why it happens to you. 28.1 as well, arch linux however.

Comment: @TerryTsao So, I suspect it's related to some config of my bash...